# Jquery autocomplete with PHP as a source not working

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json

I am new to jQuery and trying to setup a simple Autocomplete in to a text box. My Code is below:

**HTML:**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />

<script>
$(function() {
    $( "#searchstr" ).autocomplete(
    {
         source:'searchjson.php',
    })

});
</script>

<?php 
include('code.php') ;
show_header();
?>

<title>CodeLib</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div><h3>Welcome to CodeLib.com.au</h3><div>
    <h4>Articles</h4>

    <form action="index.php" method="get">
        <div class="ui-widget" >Search:(4 chars min) <input name="searchstr" id="searchstr" type="text" /></div>
</form>
</body>
```

**and my PHP code is:**

```
<?php
include("code.php");
// if the 'term' variable is not sent with the request, exit
if ( !isset($_REQUEST['searchstr']) )
    exit;

open_db();

// query the database table for zip codes that match 'term'
$rs = mysql_query('select article_title from articles where article_title like "'. mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['searchstr']) .'%" limit 10');

// loop through each zipcode returned and format the response for jQuery
$data = array();
$str = "";
if ( $rs && mysql_num_rows($rs) )
{
    while( $row = mysql_fetch_array($rs, MYSQL_ASSOC) )
    {
        $data[] = array('label' => $row['article_title']);

    }
}

// jQuery wants JSON data
echo json_encode($data);
flush();

?>
```

Few things to note:

I have tested the script using fixed values and change the source as below.
`source: availableTags` and assign fixed values in JS - Works fine

tested the PHP with a string passed in query string and I get the result as :

```
[{"label":"Simple HTML rich text editor for your web page"}]
```

But the issues is I am not getting when i assign the source to php code. Can anyone give me a clue ??

Thanks a lot.

Comment: *PSA:* The `mysql_*` functions are [deprecated in PHP 5.5](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated). It is not recommended for writing new code as it will prevent you from upgrading in the future. Instead, use either [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and [be a better PHP Developer](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/08/better-php-developer/).

Comment: Please post what searchjson.php is returning

Comment: Do you know at what point it is erroring? Is it sending the AJAX request successfully to the PHP code? Is the PHP code throwing any errors?

Comment: If you just put a submit-button in your html-code, does it work as as expected then?

Comment: I think I found the issue but still not clear why. When I call the searchjson.php, it automatically add a query string called 'term' to the end. But I was checking for "searchstr" parameter. So I replaced the searchstr with term and it works fine. But how could that happen ?? appeared to be jQuery defalut. working sample is available at http://webex40.com/

Answer (score 0):

Do you get any javascript errors?

With jQuery try to use

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    .. Your autocomplete code here
});
```

instead of `$(function() {});`

That way the `$('#searchstr')` element will exist

Comment: $(function() {}); and the $(document).ready(function() {});-option does exactly the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

It could be as easy that you have a trailing comma (especially if you're using IE) in the source-section. Try this, it might work:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $( "#searchstr" ).autocomplete(
    {
         source:'searchjson.php' //No comma at the end of this line
    })

});
</script>
```